# Passing data from VB6 to VB.NET component

Tags: .net, com, vb6

I am creating some classes in VB.NET that will be referenced by a VB6 application.  My question is what is the best way to pass information from the VB6 side to the .NET COM object?  I understand that the base data types can be passed easily, but are there any collections/arrays that can be simply passed as a VB.NET parameter?

Comment: VB6 is not exactly of fountain of collection types.  Arrays are fine.  Collection can be enumerated with IEnumerable.  You can always craft a .NET class that acts like a container and is usable by VB6 code.  Use methods like Add, Remove and an indexer.

Comment: Do you have an example of how I would pass an array?

Comment: Google already has lots of examples.  If you need help with your code then you need to post it.

Comment: Whoops sorry I got distracted and wasn't able to finish the comment.  I have tried using Microsoft.VisualBasic.VariantType and String() as my .NET method parameter types without success and can't quite seem to be able to find it by googling.

Comment: Have you found a solution? I have this same issue right now.